# d3,max from d3.stack() giving wrong maximum value

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've the following data for the stack barchart. When I try to calculate the max value for y-axis, it's giving me 100. It should be 70. Can someone let me know where am I doing wrong?

The snippet follows as below

```js
//DATA
var data = [{
        category: "test1",
        type1: 10,
        type2: 20
    },
    {
        category: "test2",
        type1: 30,
        type2: 40
    }
];
var keys = ["type1", "type2"];

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([400, 0]);
    
var stack = d3
    .stack()
    .keys(keys)
    .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetNone);

var layers = stack(data);
    
console.log(d3.max(layers[layers.length - 1], d => (d[0] + d[1])))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're adding type1 and type2 together for each stack item. The last stack is `[30,40]`. I'm not sure what stack does. So I can't answer why you expect 70.

Comment: @cgTag Am I doing something wrong with keys or the JSON data is not proper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is correct, you are finding the max of: (10 + 20) and (30 + 70) which is the latter, 100.

The stack represents each data point with two values:

> Lastly, each point is represented as an array [y0, y1] where y0 is the
>   lower value (baseline) and y1 is the upper value (topline); the
>   difference between y0 and y1 corresponds to the computed value for
>   this point. ([docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#_stack))

Given your inputs, the first category has datapoints for your types of [0,10] and [10,30] - the second point's baseline is equal to the first point's topline (baseline + value). The second category has datapoints for your types [0,30] and [30,70].

In your max function you are adding `d[0]` and `d[1]`, which reduces each of the two element arrays above to a single sum:

```
// for each item in the array layers[layers.length-1], find the max of d[0] + d[1]
d3.max(layers[layers.length - 1], d => (d[0] + d[1]))
```

This will give you 100 as the array `layers[layers.length-1]` (representing the second category's parts) is:

```
[
  [ 0 , 30 ],
  [ 30 , 70 ]
]
```

Comment: But, if we observe the data, isn't it the max value should be 70. Codepen to the chart [here](https://codepen.io/iamraviteja/pen/bOragL).

Comment: As I need the max of combined values, I need to use the above code right?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: The stack keeps track of the cumulative total of the parts. If part 1 has a value of 30, it's extent is [0,30], if part 2 picks up where part 1 ended: it starts at 30 and continues through 70 (70 being it's "topeline"), which is the cumulative total of the parts added to the stack. If you want the cumulative value of a particular column, we can use `d3.max(layers[i], d => return d[1] ))`

Comment: I want the max of all cumulative values. I think I need to use `d3.max(layers[layers.length - 1], d => d[1])` as mentioned by @rioV8. Thanks for the great explanation.

Comment: To get the max combined value of any column, we can use: `d3.max(layers, d=> d3.max(d, dd => (dd[1])))`. Though generally you could probably find the max of the last value in the stack for each column (assuming default ordering) with: `d3.max(layers, d=> d[d.length-1])`

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the max of the last elements.

```js
//DATA
var data = [{
        category: "test1",
        type1: 10,
        type2: 20
    },
    {
        category: "test2",
        type1: 30,
        type2: 40
    }
];
var keys = ["type1", "type2"];

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([400, 0]);
    
var stack = d3
    .stack()
    .keys(keys)
    .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetNone);

var layers = stack(data);

console.log(d3.max(layers[layers.length - 1], d => d[1]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```